# How to show that $(S, \oplus, \otimes)$ is a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\times)$ be a ring with additive identity $0 \in R$. On the set $S = \left.\left\{ (a,b) \,\right|\, a,b \in R \right\}$ the binary operators $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ are defined by:

- $(a, b) \oplus (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$
- $(a, b) \otimes (c, d) = (a \times c + b \times d, a \times d + b \times c)$

How do I show that $(S, \oplus, \otimes)$ is a ring? I understand the axioms which a set needs to satisfy, but I'm getting confused.

Comment: Just to give you an idea of where they got this structure from.. This ring is a split-complexification of the ring $R$. In the [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number), you have $j^2 = 1$ instead of $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Is your ring unital?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Showing it is an abelian group under $\oplus$? Showing that $\otimes$ is associative? Showing that $\otimes$ distributes over $\oplus$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show that the axioms hold one by one. Let $(a,a'),(b,b'),(c,c') \in S$.

1. Closure of addition: $(a,a')\oplus (b,b')=(a+b,a'+b') \in S$.
2. Associativity of addition: $(a,a')\oplus ((b,b') \oplus (c,c'))=(a,a')\oplus (b+c,b'+c')=(a+b+c,a'+b'+c')=(a+b,a'+b')\oplus (c,c') = ((a,b)\oplus (a',b'))\oplus (c,c')$.
3. Commutativity of addition: Try this one yourself.
4. Additive identity: Show that $(0_R,0_R)$ is the additive identity.
5. Additive inverse: Show that for an element $(a,a')$ the additive inverse is $(-a,-a)$, where $-a$ is the additive inverse of $a$ in $R$.
6. Closure of multiplication: Try this yourself. [Hint: similar to 1. but using $\otimes$ instead of $\oplus$]
7. Associativity of multiplication: Try this yourself. [Hint: similar to 2. but using $\otimes$ instead of $\oplus$]
8. Distributivity: Work out $(a,a')\otimes ((b,b')\oplus (c,c'))$. Then work out $((a,a')\otimes (b,b')) \oplus ((a,a')\otimes (c,c'))$. They are the same so distributivity holds from one side. Now you need to show similarly that $((a,a')\oplus (b,b'))\otimes (c,c') =((a,a')\otimes (c,c'))\oplus ((a,a')\otimes (b,b'))$.

I hope that helps you.